# Installing qgis2web in QGIS 3.8

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-3, error, qgis2web

I recently went to install qgis2web on QGIS3.8 Zanzibar and got the same message, irrespective of checking and installing the QtWebKit5.

I would like to be able to use the plugin in some training I am organising. Can someone help me assess this error message and revolve this issue please?

Pasted below:

```
Couldn't load plugin 'qgis2web' due to an error when calling its classFactory() method 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets' 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/share/qgis/python/qgis/utils.py", line 334, in _startPlugin
    plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
  File "/home/eoin/.var/app/org.qgis.qgis/data/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgis2web/__init__.py", line 28, in classFactory
    from .qgis2web import Qgis2Web
  File "/app/share/qgis/python/qgis/utils.py", line 737, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/home/eoin/.var/app/org.qgis.qgis/data/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgis2web/qgis2web.py", line 30, in 
    from qgis2web.maindialog import MainDialog
  File "/app/share/qgis/python/qgis/utils.py", line 737, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/home/eoin/.var/app/org.qgis.qgis/data/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgis2web/maindialog.py", line 57, in 
    from qgis.PyQt.QtWebKitWidgets import QWebView, QWebInspector, QWebPage
  File "/app/share/qgis/python/qgis/utils.py", line 737, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/app/share/qgis/python/qgis/PyQt/QtWebKitWidgets.py", line 24, in 
    from PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets import *
  File "/app/share/qgis/python/qgis/utils.py", line 737, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets'


Python version: 3.7.3 (default, Nov 10 2011, 15:00:00) [GCC 8.3.0] 
QGIS version: 3.8.3-Zanzibar Zanzibar, 685d8b15 

Python Path:
/app/share/qgis/python
/home/eoin/.var/app/org.qgis.qgis/data/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python
/home/eoin/.var/app/org.qgis.qgis/data/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins
/app/share/qgis/python/plugins
/usr/lib/python37.zip
/usr/lib/python3.7
/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload
/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages
/app/lib/python3.7/site-packages
/app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy-1.14.3-py3.7-linux-x86_64.egg
/app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MarkupSafe-1.0-py3.7-linux-x86_64.egg
/home/eoin/.var/app/org.qgis.qgis/data/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python
/home/eoin/.var/app/org.qgis.qgis/data/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/DigitizingTools/tools
/home/eoin/.var/app/org.qgis.qgis/data/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/DigitizingTools
/home/eoin/.var/app/org.qgis.qgis/data/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/mmqgis/forms
```

Comment: why don't you use the QGis plug-in manager ?

Comment: I used the plugin manager for installation and updating. Still no difference.